# Loading array from database in HREF

Tags: php, database

I want to load images from my database that if someone clicks on it brings them to another page but instead it just shows $r[n]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$cn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db', $cn);
$query="SELECT * FROM tblg";
$res=mysql_query($query,$cn);
$r = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>



<?php
if ((isset($_GET['guide']))) 
    {      
    $guide=$_GET['guide'];
    }
else 
    {
    $guide="";
    }
?>

<A HREF="?guide=$r[n]"><IMG SRC='$r[a]' WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="120" ALT="$r[n]"></A>

<?php
if ($guide == "t")
    {
    include('t.php');
    } 
elseif ($guide == "a")
    {
    include("a.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: first of all don't use the capital letters in HTML and open PHP tags/delimiters just you open in if condition. for example <a href="?guide=<?php echo $r['n'] ?>">Images</a>.

Comment: You need to use PHP's echo command to actually print the PHP variable to the page. Also, unless you are intentionally trying to print only 1 image, you need to have a `while($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<A HREF="?guide=$r[n]"><IMG SRC='$r[a]' WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="120" ALT="$r[n]"></A>
```

to

```
<A HREF="?guide=<?php echo $r[n]; ?>"><IMG SRC='<?php echo $r[a]; ?>' WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="120" ALT="<?php echo $r[n]; ?>"></A>
```

Comment: @mituw16 I have made the edit. I am not a PHP programmer, so missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<AHREF="?guide=$r[n]"><IMG SRC='$r[a]' WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="120" ALT="$r[n]"></A>
```

into

```
<a href="?guide=<?php echo $r[n]; ?>"><img src='<?php echo $r[a]; ?>' width="120" height="120" alt="<?php echo $r[n]; ?>"></a>
```

Note that using caps in your code is not really a good way of coding